# Applying for a new Indian passport when currently holding two

Tags: passports, indian-citizens

My father has two Indian passports. In the 1990's, he went to Hong Kong with a genuine passport with his correct name. When he came back to India he lost his passport and applied for a new one. Due to a mix-up, the new passport came with a different name. The person in charge said that this is okay. A few months later, my father found his original passport. At the time, he didn’t care and didn’t cancel the new passport because didn’t travel anywhere after coming back from Hong Kong.

I, his daughter, am now living in Australia. I told my father to apply for a new passport because the old one has expired. He went to the passport office and told them the whole story. Initially, they said that they would send a letter for police verification, but they did no verification and called my father to come to the passport office.

When my father went there they said that you have to pay penalty fee of ₹100,000 for it. My father told them that this would be difficult, and that he had done nothing and told them the truth. He added that hadn’t even travelled anywhere since getting the last passport. They are now asking for ₹50,000 from him.

This is very annoying. If penalty fees were really that high, then how come they have now been halved?

I want to bring him to Australia and it is so difficult to get a passport for him.

How can I get him a passport?

And please also let me know what the appropriate penalty fee should be.

Comment: Related (not a duplicate): http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/61083/two-indian-passports-in-one-name

Comment: It was actually quite easy to understand, @pnuts. I didn't have to reorganize anything, just reword it. I've seen far worse questions from native speakers.

Comment: Also related: http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/60404/253 and http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/17194/253.

Comment: You get him a passport by doing whatever the Indian passport authorities want, or by convincing the Indian passport authorities that the things they want are unreasonable. It sounds like he needs a lawyer, not the advice of well-meaning but unqualified strangers on the internet.

Comment: Sounds like baksheesh?